# ViewState, Session, Hidden Form Fields, and QueryString for state management ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm learning ASP.NET and C# and I have a few questions since reading the msdn page was confusing.

I need to Know how and when to use ViewState, Session, Hidden Form Fields, and QueryString for state management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ViewState :**

A ViewState is perfect if you only want the object to live for the current page's life cycle.

**Session State :**

For data that needs to persist for a user’s entire session across multiple pages you should use Session State

**Hidden Form Field :**

The hidden field can be used to store data that needs to persist across multiple post backs, when your viewstate disable.

Use with javascript ( because it is plain text )

**Querystring :**

Pass values between pages, which is not confidential

More Information :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7(v=vs.140).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management

Answer (score -3):

Don't use QueryStrings for session management. That is super risky and really vulnerable to session hijacking.

Using Session[] is also known to be somewhat insecure. Only store information in the Session that is not incredibly sensitive information.

Look into the FormsAuthentication class (SetAuthCookie) function for something fairly simple.

For a better implementation of sessions and authentication, look into ASP Memberships [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).